# Check if given date is in last 3 weeks

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I have a sample date:

```
const date = '10-03-2022';
```

I need to check if this date is longer than 3 weeks or not. Or speaking differently - I need to check if this date is in the last 3 weeks or older.

I was trying with `date-fns` but its not the result I expect.

```
import { formatDistance, subWeeks } from 'date-fns'

formatDistance(subWeeks(new Date(), 3), date)
```

I dont have to be honest any idea how to deal with such problem. Thats why I wanted to ask you here for help. Thanks!

Comment: You need to parse `date`. Then use `subWeeks()` to get the date 3 weeks ago. Finally, test if the parsed date is after that result.

Comment: @Barmar I was thinking about that. But is there any cleaner solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`isAfter`](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/isAfter) to compare against [`subWeeks`](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/subWeeks). This will return true even if the date is in the future from `now`.

Alternatively you can use [`isWithinInterval`](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/isWithinInterval) to test if the date is within the period between `now` and three weeks before `now`. (not included in the cdn version available).

```
const dateIsWithinInterval = isWithinInterval(testDate,
    { start: subWeeks(new Date(), 3), end: new Date() })
```

You'll still need to parse your string into a valid Date object.

```js
//import { isAfter, subWeeks } from 'date-fns';
const { isAfter, subWeeks } = dateFns; // cdn assignment

const dateString = '10-06-2022';
const [d, m, y] = dateString.split('-').map(n => parseInt(n, 10));
// months are 0 indexed so you need to subrtract 1.
const testDate = new Date(y, m - 1, d);

const dateIsAfter = isAfter(testDate, subWeeks(new Date(), 3));

console.log('isAfter:', dateIsAfter);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/2.0.0-alpha0/date_fns.min.js" integrity="sha512-0kon+2zxkK5yhflwFqaTaIhLVDKGVH0YH/jm8P8Bab/4EOgC/n7gWyy7WE4EXrfPOVDeNdaebiAng0nsfeFd9A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```